# Ring homomorphism between real numbers and real valued functions

Tags: ring-theory, abstract-algebra

I was going through chapter 10 in Artin there I found following proposition -

[image]

Here I am unable to figure out how the homomorphism function will look like in from Real no.'s to Ring of real valued continuous functions coz as mentioned in first line of proof substitution principle is used to show the map from real polynomial R[x] to real valued polynomial function. I was thinking it to be as -

$$\phi(1) = identitymap$$
$$\phi(0) = zeromap$$
$$\phi(k) = \phi(1+1+...ktimes) = k*identity map$$

Is it correct?
Also isn't it an isomorphic map from R[x1,..xn] to R??

Comment: The polynomial $x^2-3x+5$ is sent to the real-valued function $f(x) = x^2-3x+5$. $\varphi$ is not an isomorphic map, as there are many, many real-valued functions which are not polynomials.

Comment: For example, if $f$ is the polynomial $3x_1^2 + x_1 x_2$ (a formal expression), then $\varphi(f)$ is the function that takes an ordered pair $(x,y)$ and returns  $3x^2 + xy$. The "substitution principle" means that the mapping $f \mapsto \varphi(f)$ makes sense and is a homomorphism, but doesn't imply on its own that this mapping is injective.

Comment: Hi Arthur, can you please tell me what would be the map from real numbers to real valued continuous functions

Comment: For real numbers (constant polynomials), the map maps to the constant function, $$\mathbb{R}\ni c \mapsto (x\mapsto c).$$

Answer (score 1):

Artin is claiming that if you map every formal polynomial $p(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ in $n$ variables with real coefficients  to the function

$
f_p:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, (a_1,\ldots ,a_n)\mapsto p(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)
$

then this maps $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\ldots ,x_n]$ injectively into the ring $R$ of real valued continous functions $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Of course this map is not surjective, because there exist non-polynomial continous functions.

Comment: Thanks Hagen, but I am still dubious about first line of proof which says that with substitution principle the existance of this map is guranteed

Comment: In my eyes the substitution principle is mentioned to make clear, that a formal polynomial can be considered as a map $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which is a priori not clear considering the algebraic construction of polynomials.